# react native - Callback in component with 'prop-types'

Tags: react-native, callback, react-proptypes

I have Gallery component like:

```
import React from 'react';
... Some import
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
    TouchableOpacity,
    Image,
    FlatList
} from 'react-native';

export default class Gallery extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selected: 0,
            data: this.props.data
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                horizontal={true}
                data={this.state.data}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                renderItem={({item, index}) =>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        disabled={this.props.overlay && this.state.selected==index}
                        // onPress={this.props.actionOnPress}
                        onPress={()=>{
                            if(this.props.overlay) {
                                this.setState({
                                    selected: index,
                                    data: [...this.props.data]
                                });
                            }
                            this.props.actionOnPress;
                        }}>
                        <Image
                            source={{uri: item.imageUrl}}
                            style={[gallery.galleryItem, this.props.overlay && this.state.selected!=index ?gallery.overlay :  null,
                            index==0 ? gallery.firstGalleryItem : ( index+1 == Object.keys(this.props.data).length ? gallery.lastGalleryItem : null )]}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
            />
        );
    }
}
Gallery.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array,
    actionOnPress: PropTypes.func,
    overlay: PropTypes.bool
}
```

and I have used Gallery component like

```
import React from 'react';
import common from '../../assets/styles/common/common'
import galleryPreview from '../../assets/styles/common/galleryPreview'
import icons from '../../assets/styles/common/icon'
import Icons from '../../config/ConstantIcon'
import Gallery from '../common/Gallery'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Image
} from 'react-native';

const data = [ List item here];

export default class GalleryPreview extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                ... Some code here

                    <Gallery data={data} overlay={true}/>

                ... Some code here
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

How to use callback from Gallery component like `<Gallery data={data} actionOnPress={({item, index})=> console.log(item)}/>`. `item` and `index` will be get from Gallery component.

I have used `onPress={this.props.actionOnPress}` but I can not insert

```
if(this.props.overlay) {
    this.setState({
        selected: index,
        data: [...this.props.data]
    });
}
```

and not callback param `item` and `index`

can you guys help me?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function with the arguments:

```
onPress={() => {
  ...
  this.props.actionOnPress({ item, index });
}}
```